# why cannot load an object inside another?

Tags: php, object

I just don't understand why i can't call an object like this.

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array (
        "happy" => " :) ",
        "sad" => " :( "
);

class MyClass
{
    function __construct () {}

    function something ()
    {
        echo "Hello World\n";
        echo $obj->sad;
    }
}

$class = new MyClass();
echo $obj->happy;
$class->something();
```

the output seem like

```
:) Hello World
```

and it's not what I expect. i.e.

```
:) Hello World :(
```

how can I make this work??

EDIT:
This is in what I will implement this example. [passing objects from the global scope to a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074908/passing-objects-from-the-global-scope-to-a-model)

Comment: Turn on error display, read up on variable scope. `something()` cannot see `$obj`.

Comment: The problem @DCoder is not the error, I just want to make $obj visible in all the function inside MyClass :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array (
        "happy" => " :) ",
        "sad" => " :( "
);

class MyClass
{
    function __construct (){
    }

    function something ()
    {
        global $obj;
        echo "Hello World\n";
        echo $obj->sad;
    }
}

$class = new MyClass();
echo $obj->happy;
$class->something();

?>
```

That will be **a way** of doing it.
obj is not in scope here, you have to either make it global, or pass it.

Pass it to constructor and save instance..as here

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array (
        "happy" => " :) ",
        "sad" => " :( "
);

class MyClass
{   private $obj;
    function __construct ($obj) {
     $this->obj=$obj;

    }

    function something ()
    {
        echo "Hello World\n";
        echo $this->obj->sad;
    }
}

$class = new MyClass($obj);
echo $obj->happy;
$class->something();
```

But you will have to access $obj as $this->obj from all functions

Comment: Cool. But I still need to declare `global $obj` inside each function of MyClass. and i have ~23 function on a class :P. I know it's just copy and paste. there's no other way to make $obj visible in every scope?

Comment: you will still have to change all functions...no way out

Comment: haha thanks so much. I'll take the first method because it's for a model of codeigniter and there's no way to pass a parameter in the constructor ( as far I know )

Comment: u can pass it some other function though ...some function like setObject($obj) {$this->obj=$obj}

Comment: mmmmm seems like it's not working. I'll make another question with the full code of the model. it's really wierd whats happening :/ and I hate php, but it's what buy my food lol

Answer (score 4):

`$obj` is not defined inside the scope of the `something` function. You could globalise it by adding `global $obj` inside the function, but it would be better to pass it as an argument to the function.

EDIT:

```
<?php
$obj = (object) Array(
    "happy" => " :) ",
    "sad" => " :( "
);
class MyClass {
  function something($obj) {
    echo "Hello World\n".$obj->sad;
  }
}
$class = new MyClass();
echo $obk->happy;
$class->something($obj);
```

Comment: making $obj global breaks all the code :/ i've already tried. edit: inside in which function?

Comment: Global isn't safe any ways and should always be avoided at all costs

Answer (score 1):

Pass obj as a parameter to either the constructor or the method itself, here is an example using the method:

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array (
        "happy" => " :) ",
        "sad" => " :( "
);

class MyClass
{
    function __construct () {}

    function something ($obj)
    {
        echo "Hello World\n";
        echo $obj->sad;
    }
}

$class = new MyClass();
echo $obj->happy;
$class->something($obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your case `$obj` is in global scope and is not available withing the scope of your class.

Turn on your error reporting and this would become evident right away with a "trying to get a property of a non-object" type of error.